# How to check if an NSDocument has unsaved changes?

Tags: save, nsdocument

I know how to tell `NSDocument` that there are new changes, with `-(void)updateChangeCount:`. But, I can't find a method `changeCount` or something like this  to check if an NSDocument has unsaved changes.

Is there a way to check that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for `-[NSDocument isDocumentEdited]`?